# Why Beautifulsoup4 cycle gives me the 'NoneType' error?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to repeat the scrapbooking tutorial. I'm stuck because of the error, which i dont get, because I am newbie

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

browser = Chrome('C:\Jupyter lab home dir\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.avito.ru/nizhnevartovsk/vakansii?cd=1'
browser.get(url)

obyavs = soup.find_all('h3', class_='iva-item-title-py3i_') # list of divs

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')           # what we are looking for 
name = soup.find('h3', class_='iva-item-title-py3i_').text
zp = soup.find('span', class_='price-text-_YGDY').text.replace('\xa0000', '000').replace('\xa0₽', '')
graphic = soup.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[0]
gde_rab = soup.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[1]
description = soup.find('div', class_='iva-item-description-FDgK4').text.replace('\n', '')
type_of_job = soup.find('span', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text
geo_address = soup.find('div', class_='geo-address-fhHd0').text
date_of_creation = soup.find('div', class_='date-text-KmWDf').text

data = []
for obyav in obyavs:                                               # parsing
    name = obyav.find('h3', class_='iva-item-title-py3i_').text
    zp = obyav.find('span', class_='price-text-_YGDY').text.replace('\xa0000', '000').replace('\xa0₽', '')
    graphic = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[0]
    gde_rab = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[1]
    description = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-description-FDgK4').text.replace('\n', '')
    type_of_job = obyav.find('span', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text
    geo_address = obyav.find('div', class_='geo-address-fhHd0').text
    date_of_creation = obyav.find('div', class_='date-text-KmWDf')
    data.append([name, zp, graphic, gde_rab, description, type_of_job, geo_address, date_of_creation])
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6e3X.png)

It says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the error for us to be able to answer this definitively, but one of your `find` lookups is likely not finding the element. Double check the class, and ensure the element is statically loaded. If it's dynamically loaded using JS, you can't use BS4 for this. You'll need to use something like Selenium to run the JS to load the elements.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you for your reply! When I soup.find -its ok, and when I item.find ('obyav' in my case, in cycle )- it says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: As I mentioned, that means that that `h3` tag does not exist. Double-check the class, hierarchy, and ensure that the element you're trying to select is loaded statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the tag by which you are looking for vacancies `obyava = soup.find_all('h3', class_='iva-item-title-py3i_')`, replace with `obyavs = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-body-KLUuy').` And you also need to process the test method in the try, except block. Here is a working code that will return what you are looking for.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = Chrome('/home/denis/Загрузки/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.avito.ru/nizhnevartovsk/vakansii?cd=1'
browser.get(url)

browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')           # what we are looking for 
obyavs = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-body-KLUuy') # list of divs

data = []
for obyav in obyavs:                                         # parsing
    try:
        name = obyav.find('h3', class_='iva-item-title-py3i_').text
    except AttributeError:
        name = "No name"
    try:
        zp = obyav.find('span', class_='price-text-_YGDY').text.replace('\xa0000', '000').replace('\xa0₽', '')
    except AttributeError:
        name = "No zp"
    try:
        graphic = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[0]
    except AttributeError:
        graphic = "No graphic"
    try:
        gde_rab = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text.split(' · ')[1]
    except AttributeError:
        gde_rab = "No gde_rab"
    try:
        description = obyav.find('div', class_='iva-item-description-FDgK4').text.replace('\n', '')
    except AttributeError:
        description = "No description"
    try:
        type_of_job = obyav.find('span', class_='iva-item-text-Ge6dR').text
    except AttributeError:
        type_of_job = "No type_of_job"
    try:
        geo_address = obyav.find('div', class_='geo-address-fhHd0').text
    except AttributeError:
        geo_address = "No geo_address"
    try:
        date_of_creation = obyav.find('div', class_='date-text-KmWDf')
    except AttributeError:
        geo_address = "date_of_creation"
    l = [name, zp, graphic, gde_rab, description, type_of_job, geo_address, date_of_creation]
    print(l)
    data.append(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' means that the code is trying to access the 'text' attribute of a variable that is None. In this case, it seems that one of the variables (probably date_of_creation) is not finding any matching element in the HTML and returning None instead of a BeautifulSoup object.

To fix this, you can add a check to make sure the variable is not None before trying to access its 'text' attribute. For example:

if date_of_creation is not None:
date_of_creation = date_of_creation.text
else:
date_of_creation = ''

This will set date_of_creation to an empty string if the element is not found, instead of raising an error. You can apply this same check to any other variables that might be causing similar errors

Comment: "[Y]ou can add a check to make sure the variable is not None before trying to access its 'text' attribute": while this is true, all this does is cover up the problem if they expect that element to exist. If they implement this suggestion, I expect the followup question to be "now empty strings are being added to the list".

Comment: @Roman thanks for your reply. I guess its not really what Im trying to get.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I guess I will try to go your way